# Broadcast Receiver class send status to fragment

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver as part of my class, in moving the Broadcast receiver to its own class I am not able to return any sort of value back to the class that needs that data. Is there a way to set the data and then send it back to the class that has registered it?

The Overview Class should be able to pick up the status of what the BatteryReceiver class issues.

```
public class Overview extends Fragment {

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    private BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BatteryReceiver();

    @BindView(R.id.bat_generic)
    TextView batText;

    public Overview() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Overview newInstance() {
        return new Overview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle outState) {
        super.onCreate(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        try {
            initView();

            getActivity().registerReceiver(
                    batteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
            );

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unbinder.unbind();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
    }

    private void initView() {

        batText.setText(
          // TODO: logic  
        );
}
```

The BatteryReceiver class should be able to send the data back to the class that implements it.

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int deviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        int percentage = (int) (((float) level / (float) scale) * 100.0f);

        switch (deviceStatus) {
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
                context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Charging:", percentage, "%");
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING:
                context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Discharging:", percentage, "%");
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
                context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Full:", percentage, "%");
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN:
                context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Unknown:", percentage, "%");
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING:
                context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Not charging:", percentage, "%");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't register a broadcast in a class that isn't context but there is a way around you can pass context to other class.

```
        // implements OnBatteryChange in your activity
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnBatteryChange {...
    // add following method in your activity
     @Override
      public void batteryChanged(String data) {
        txtBat.setText(data);
      }
    // add following line in onCreate() in activity

    OtherReceiver reciever = new OtherReceiver(getApplicationContext(),this);
    reciever.doSomethingWithReceivedIntent();

        //OtherReceiver class

        public class OtherReceiver {
    Context context;
    OnBatteryChange batteryChange;

    public OtherReceiver(Context context, OnBatteryChange batteryChange) {
        this.context = context;
        this.batteryChange = batteryChange;
    }

    public void doSomethingWithReceivedIntent() {
        BatteryReceiver batteryReceiver = new BatteryReceiver();
        batteryReceiver.setBatteryChange(batteryChange);
        context.registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }
}

    //OnBatteryChange interface

    public interface OnBatteryChange {
        void batteryChanged(String data);
    }

    //amend BatteryReceiver to following code 
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    OnBatteryChange batteryChange;

    public void setBatteryChange(OnBatteryChange batteryChange) {
        this.batteryChange = batteryChange;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int deviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        int percentage = (int) (((float) level / (float) scale) * 100.0f);

        switch (deviceStatus) {
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:

                batteryChange.batteryChanged(context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Charging:", percentage, "%"));
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING:

                batteryChange.batteryChanged(context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Discharging:", percentage, "%"));
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:

                batteryChange.batteryChanged(context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Full:", percentage, "%"));
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN:

                batteryChange.batteryChanged(context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Unknown:", percentage, "%"));
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING:

                batteryChange.batteryChanged(context.getString((R.string.bat_charge), "Not charging:", percentage, "%"));
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

for unregistering you can define another method too.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example, written or otherwise demonstrating this please?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, I wanted to ask if you could explain what it is you do here in the context of setting the text to the TextView batText

Comment: Thank you Vahid, this was extremely helpful! I can reuse this for other BroadcastReceivers as well!